# Problem running php on shtml page .. php not parsing

Tags: php

**Problems using PHP on a shtml page with network solutions.**

I am using a PHP include for my headers and footers ..used to work just fine, then boom no longer works. There was nothing changed by me on my site.

NS is no help they recommended modifying my .htaccsess file but provided no information on what to include in the file.

The server runs php 7.0.02

I have tried all below in the .htaccsess file and yes the file is in the root directory for the site and is uploaded in ASCII

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .html .htm .shtml


AddType application/x-httpd-php70 .htm .html .shtml
```

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .shtml

AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html .shtml
```

When I use AddHandler nothing happens, when I use AddType the page wants to download itself.

Also tried these:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.(html|htm|shtml)$ - [H=application/x-httpd-php70]
```

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.(html|htm|shtml)$ - [T=application/x-httpd-php70]
```

RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteRule \.(html|htm|shtml)$ - [H=application/x-httpd-php]
```

```
RewriteRule \.(html|htm|shtml)$ - [T=application/x-httpd-php]
```

```
<Files *.shtml>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

I really do not want to have to go in and change all the pages to a php extension as there are a ton of links that would have to be changed as well, and I would prefer the pages not show with a php extension.

If anyone can shed some light on why I can not get this to work with network Solutions it would be greatly appreciated.

5/7/2019 .. Well I guess it is time to abort the mission and just use PHP pages and use a rewrite rule to remove the PHP extension from the address bar as my hosting service says that PHP can not be parsed in any way shape or form from my HTML pages by them.. seems odd, but tired of beating my head against a wall on this.

Comment: Have you tried putting `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .html .htm .shtml` in the server configuration? Have you confirmed that's an appropriate handler and is installed properly?

Comment: Milken32 .. not sure if I have the ability to modify the server configuration or not.
As far as confirming if it is the proper handler all Network Solutions has done so far is referred me to articles on this site – How would I potentially go about checking this without their assistance as they are not exactly helpful or forthcoming .. I think they would prefer to put me on ignore

Comment: If you can’t change the server config you probably can’t check what modules are installed. Sorry, didn’t realize you weren’t on your own server.

Comment: About to call NS yet again I can ask them about handlers .. anything specific I should be asking them?